# Improve the usability of the suggested edits review page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

I know I should pay more attention and not do these things when I'm tired but I would say that the review page for suggested edits is not user friendly.

The topic of the edit could really be more prominent.

For example see this screenshot of a tag edit review item and see how insignificant one of the most important pieces of information is:

[image]

I think the UX of the review section in general is not great but this example is probably the worst of it.

Does anyone agree or should I just get more sleep :)

Would it be possible to change this in any way or not likely?

Comment: I'm assuming this is global to the entire network? If so, it would probably be better to ask on https://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: +1 from me.  This has bitten me as well: http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/a/3190/12076

Answer (score 1):

I feel with you rooby. Moreover you're not the only one suffering that problem. Go checkout " [Is there a way to get edit feedback?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/645/is-there-a-way-to-get-edit-feedback) ", in which I at first added a (frustrated) reply, a bit later responded to by "Free Radical", who seemed to have suffered the exact same problem like you described here. The (right away accepted) 'mea culpa' there came in right on time, because I (as a new-bee around here), was about to give up (which I NEVER do however).

In the meantime I've kept improving (I think), with quite some suggested edits the last week or so, and I can't remember anymore when was my last rejected edit. And about an hour ago I received an unexpected "reputation" surprise (at first I thought the SE-system was suffering some kind of bug/error, until I realised that "somebody" seemed to have noticed (understood) my recent contributions, including some (constructive) critique. Right now I'm still waiting the verdict about my [json](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/json) tag edit suggestion, for over 2 days (!!) now.

I learned from mistakes, even though there is hardly any real feedback from anyone (when 1 out of 3 reviewers marks a suggested as rejected). So maybe your suggestion should be enhanced with some type of person-to-person discussion (chat?) between the reviewer and the author, to explain the rejection, and give an opportunity to the author to learn from mistakes. Better still: come up with some collaboration technique between the author and rejector to further enhance the suggested edit, a kind of negotiation process between those 2 parties.

Anyway, I'm voting up your suggestion!

Comment: As an aside, I approved your JSON edit. I also made a follow up edit. The changes are live if you click the "learn more..." link on that json taxonomy page.

Comment: This issue is more specifically about the UI. Being able to leave feedback would also be good though.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Not sure where to find that "learn more" (I do not see that anywhere). And on http://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/51238 it appears like nothing has changed today regarding JSON suggested edit (so still waiting for the final verdict from ...???)

Comment: Oh sorry, I approved an earlier edit, then made an edit, then you are talking about another newer edit.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I'll be AbitMORE patient for "the" verdict about JSON (day nr 3 will start soon). Suspense!

Comment: For a bit more information, something that isn't really apparent to most users is that there are not all that many users with enough reputation to perform certain review tasks on things and then only a small portion of those users that actually do have/make the time to actually review things. On top of that there are limits to the number of review tasks you are allowed to do in one day, so if you haven't been to the site for a while and there are a couple of hundred review items then it takes a long time to get through them all with the daily limit.

Comment: The reason for the daily limit is to try to get a more diverse range of users doing the reviews.